# The reason of warnings for installing my application

Tags: android, warnings

I have a simple application that I just added a splash screen and there is any permission to use my app. I wanna know whats the reason of warning when I wanna install it.
Its the warning text :

```
This app may be harmful and damage your device or data. We do not recommend that you install this app.
```

Im really confused. Its just a simple app.

Comment: This is usually displayed during installation, when the device cannot recognize the signature of the package or faces unusual signature. It is nothing to worry I think.

Comment: Thanks. It has happened when I wanna install it on another device too. Is there any solution for that?

Comment: I think, there is no solution.

Comment: Its really annoying me